# How to update time-to-live(TTL) of existing records in Cassandra DB?

Tags: database

As Cassandra DB is providing a option to set Time-to-live(TTL) value to automatically delete the record on the basis of TTL value set with record. I have a case that user can change the date of data expiry, means user can change the data expiration date any time.

**Case:**

1. Suppose default expiration period is 10 days.
2. Then inserted some records with setting TTL for 10 days.
3. after 2 days user change expiration period to 30 days.
4. But the previous data inserted with 10 days TTL period automatically gets deleted after 10 days instead of 30 days.

**Requirement:** Whenever user changes the expiration period through UI, we wanted to change TTL in database.
    Is there any option to update the TTL for records in Cassandra DB.

Comment: I have also read details about this new database and it really nice manage data with expire period. I also needs this questions answers so that I will also use this database.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did some R&D on this issue and I have concluded following points.

1. **We can increase TTL for any record in Cassandra DB but it needs to reset all fields with update query for individual record**.
2. **We can’t reduce TTL for any record at any cost. Even if you update record with less TTL value, the record will remain in database till maximum TTL value which is either old or new. updated value**.

Comment: Thank you for this naswer.
Now, in cassandra 2.2.4, point number 2 is invalid.
You can reduce the TTL of one entry.
The first point is always valid.

`DROP TABLE test;
CREATE TABLE test (
    a text PRIMARY KEY,
    b text,
    c text
);

select a, b, TTL(b), c, TTL(c) from test;
INSERT INTO test (a,b,c) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c') USING TTL 60;
select a, b, TTL(b), c, TTL(c) from test;

UPDATE test USING TTL 200 SET b = 'b' WHERE a = 'a';
select a, b, TTL(b), c, TTL(c) from test;

UPDATE test USING TTL 10 SET c = 'c' WHERE a = 'a';
select a, b, TTL(b), c, TTL(c) from test;`

Answer (score 5):

You can perform a "fake update"

```
INSERT INTO ttl_example (k, v) VALUES ('somekey', 'somevalue') USING TTL 60;
UPDATE ttl_example USING TTL 200 SET v = 'somevalue' WHERE k = 'somekey';
```

After the execution of second statement TTL will be 200 seconds.

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: Thanks....it works. But my table having 20+ columns so while doing fake update I have to firstly fetch all the data and then it need to set in Update query.  Since actual table contains 10000+ data, it is very time consuming process. Is there any shorter way to do it?  I need a simple way only a single query to do it.

Comment: Also I concluded that we can't reduce the TTL at any cost.

Comment: This only update the TTL of the updated columns, not the row.

Re-INSERTing the row seems to be the way to go (depending on the user case).

Answer (score 1):

This work on Cassandra 2.0.7
You can RE-INSERT the same data changing only TTL.

INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2 ) VALUES ( '001','aaa') USING TTL 200;
INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2 ) VALUES ( '001','aaa') USING TTL 2;
Wait 2 sec and the row disappear;

I found also this by DataStax:
To change the TTL of a specific column, you must re-insert the data with a new TTL. Apache Cassandra™ upserts the column with the new TTL, replacing the old value with the old TTL, if any exists.

See this [link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_expire_c.html)

Comment: yeah, but if the data is flushed and compacted during those 2 seconds I think the "ghost" lives on in some sstables